# rails newbie: how to get params from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

i've been thinking about this way to long. I'm pretty sure that you will find my mistake super fast. As i've read at least ten similar threads/questions with nearly the same "problem" I think I figured what "the problem" might be, but don't know how to solve it.

my question after thinking like three hours about it:
why doesn't my editview recieve the params of `<%= link_to 'bearbeiten', edit_tour_tn_path(@tour, t) %` ?

in detail:

I'am working with nested resources (as described in the getting started guide): 
one tour has_many tns, one tn belongs_to a tour.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :tours do 
  resources :tns  
end
```

**tns_controller.rb**

```
class TnsController < ApplicationController

  def create
   @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
   @tn = @tour.tns.create(tn_params)
   redirect_to tour_path(@tour)
  end

 def new
  @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
  @tn = @tour.tns.create(tn_params)
 end

 def index
  @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
  @tns = @tour.tns.all
 end

def edit
  @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
  @tn = @tour.tns.find(params[:id])

 if @tn.update(tn_params)
   redirect_to tour_tns_path
 else
   render 'edit'
 end
end

def show
  @tn = Tn.find(params[:id])
end

private
 def tn_params
  params.require(:tn).permit(:vorname, :nachname, :gender, :bdate, :email, :telefon, :schwimmen, :besonderheit, :eek, :fotog, :notfallk, :kkh)
end

end
```

**view: form_for snippet:**

```
  <%= form_for([@tour, @tour.tns.build]) do |f| %>
   #with many more fields, but i think they aren't relevant for my problem
```

**view: show tour and its tns** (like 'show blogpost and comments' in the tutorial)

```
<p> TeilnehmerInnen:
    <table>
    <th>Vorname</th>
    <th>Nachname</th>
    <th>Alter</th>
    <th>Bearbeiten</th>
    <th>Löschen</th>

<tr><% @tour.tns.each do |t| %>
<td><%= t.vorname %> </td>
<td><%= t.nachname %></td>
<td><%= ((DateTime.now - t.bdate)/ 365.25).to_i %> Jahre</td>
<td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_tour_tn_path(tour_id: t) %></td>
<td>#mülleimer verlinken</td>
</tr>   
    <% end %>
 </table>
</p>
```

if i click the 'bearbeiten' link to edit a tour_tn, i get the popular

> "param is missing or the value is empty: tn"

referring to the private def tn_params thing:

> app/controllers/tns_controller.rb:35:in `tn_params'
>    app/controllers/tns_controller.rb:22:in`edit'

but as the request goes along with the parameters

> Parameters:
>
> {"tour_id"=>"3",
>    "id"=>"5"}

i don't understand how my edit form (which is rendering the above mentioned form_for) doesn't get the param.

Could you be so kind and show me the tree in front of my nose? :>

kind regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

this will pass id into your edit action

```
<td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_tour_tn_path(t) %></td>
```

if you want to sent some extra parameter using

```
<td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_tour_tn_path(id: t) %></td>
```

edit action

```
def edit
  @tour = Tour.find(params[:tn][:tour_id])
  @tn = @tour.tns.find(params[:id])

 if @tn.update(tn_params)
   redirect_to tour_tns_path
 else
   render 'edit'
 end
end
```

Comment: Hey vipin, thanks for your quick response! I did already try something like that - if i use the second trick i get an "No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"tns", :id=>"...} missing required keys: [:tour_id].  And when i put the '@tour‘ back in the brackets i am back at the beginning / same _error: param is missing or the value is empty: tn_

Comment: try this : <td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_tour_tn_path(tour_id:  t) %></td> and easy to get into your controller action by params[:tns][:tour_id]

Comment: still the same: ´ActionController::ParameterMissing in TnsController#edit param is missing or the value is empty: tn ´

Comment: did so: "NoMethodError in TnsController#edit   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" xD
and when i put the two params in brackets, like @tour = Tour.find(params([:tn][:tour_id])) in the editaction, it delivers a TypeError "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" - i guess this is where my lack of experience is braking... :o

Comment: but I think my original problem is solved (or at least has changed to something new i can google^^)  thank you very much!

Comment: Started GET "/tours/3/tns/3/edit" for ::1 at 2016-07-01 12:19:04 +0200
Processing by TnsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"tour_id"=>"3", "id"=>"3"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
  app/controllers/tns_controller.rb:19:in `[]'
  app/controllers/tns_controller.rb:19:in `edit'

Comment: okay now you can get params like params[:tour_id]  and params[:id]